# Create 1 array with 2 fields from 2 csv fields in BigQuery

Tags: arrays, google-bigquery

I am currently trying to work through this and I'm unsure as to how to proceed.  I have the below data

| ID | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | a,b,c | 10,20,30 |

I would like to turn it into
| ID   | properties.name     | properties.value    |
|:---- |:------:  | -----:   |
| One  | a        |  10      |
|      | b        |  20      |
|      | c        |  30      |

The below query looked like it was working but instead of having an array it created a nested record with 2 array fields.

```
SELECT ID
  name
  , value
  , array (
          select as struct
            split(name, ',') as name
            , split(value, ',') as value
        ) as properties
        
   
FROM `orders`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, array(
    select as struct name, value
    from unnest(split(name)) name with offset
    join unnest(split(value)) value with offset
    using(offset)
  ) as properties
from `orders`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly!  I'm still getting used to using arrays in BigQuery so appreciate the help.